# C# using FileOpendialogbox control within my form class

Tags: c#, fileopendialog

I have a weird requirement. I need to use FileOpenDialogBox control within my form. I mean not as other window but as control of a form. I know many applicationss that doing it. How can I do it in C#?

Comment: It is available in the Windows API code pack.  Works only on Vista and up.

Answer (score 2):

Try [this object](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/FileBrowser.aspx) I found on the web.

Comment: It kind of helped me but not entirely. Thanks for your answer.